# fabric.js make active object on top of others when dragging

Tags: fabricjs

my question is, fabric.js makes active object on top of others when dragging.

I know a property can do this, can't remind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
canvas.add(red, blue); // add youre objects..

function myDrag(e) {   // funciton on drag (moving)
  e.target.bringToFront();
}

canvas.on({
  'object:moving': myDrag,
});
```

Want to add more events? Use the Event inspector @ [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/events/)

I made a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm7LJ/). Hopes it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since you asked this but I want to answer it if anyone would stuck for that.

This behavior is default in fabric js right know but if you want to change it just set `preserveObjectStacking` to `false` when initializing the canvas. See more in [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#preserveObjectStacking).